# Winning streaks in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, gaps-and-islands

As the title says - I have a Postgres database with players and matches, and I want to get a list of the winning streaks. Note that I'm not just interested in the numbers, i.e., I see a lot of questions on Stackoverflow concerning just the highest winning streak - I want to be able to get more data and details about the streaks, such as all the games.

Specifically, this is the DB I'm looking at: http://aligulac.com/about/db/. I've created a view based on this that has the essential columns, basically looking like this:

```
player_id | match_id | score
-------------------------------
82        | 2847     |  2
82        | 3733     |  3
82        | 4348     |  1
82        | 5237     |  1
82        | 5363     |  3
82        | 7274     | -1
51        | 2347     |  3
51        | 3746     |  2
51        | 5037     |  3
51        | 7269     | -1
...       | ...      |  ...
```

"score" is "player_score - opponent_score", so I want the streaks of positive scores from the same player without interruption. A resulting table could look like this:

```
player_id | match_id | streak
-------------------------------
82        | 5363     |  5
51        | 5037     |  3
...       | ...      |  ...
```

Which would allow me to retrieve the last match of a streak, and since I know how long the streak was, also all the matches before the streak. Is there a good way to store an array of IDs such that I could store all relevant matchIDs that were part of the streak in the row as well? Maybe in an enum or so?

What I did so far is to make a Postgres view of all matches, ordered by player ID/match ID, exported it into Excel CSV, and then used an Excel formula + filters to arrive at the result. It looks like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTYxtU1GvK5ZkcjOUEalHEfplLP42NAuEtor-HpNopn8HkaZq_tCyQKjLun90rHI_JHNQ17CQdTqcAM/pubhtml) currently. But of course that's not really easy to update and I'd love to be able to do it via Query directly, or at least part of it - or even better using the Aligulac API (http://aligulac.com/about/api/).

Any ideas for how to do something along those lines? Thanks!

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images  - or even worse - links to images.

Comment: Sounds like a "gaps and islands" problem.

Comment: Sorry @jarlh - didn't know it was so bad. Those weren't links to images, it's a link to the DB and the resulting Google Sheets table to provide some context. But I've added tables that abstract the core of the issue which will hopefully help in making this more accessible. Grateful for any other advice on how to improve the question, or a potential solution.

Comment: In your view you need a column that defines ordering of rows, you cannot find series on an unordered dataset. The column may be e.g. an integer primary key or a timestamp / date column (date of a match), or something similar.

Comment: @klin good point, didn't think of that. When creating the view I order it by "player_id, match_id" and then exported it to Excel - which worked just fine. The date of match is irrelevant because there's oftentimes many matches per day per player, so match_id might be a better order. Can I just use the tuple "player_id, match_id"? Since you can't add primary keys to Postgres views.

Comment: Yes, `(player_id, match_id)` is sufficient for this, though your expected output would change then.

Comment: Aaaaah because the match_id entries are not in sequential order. I just typed in random keys to illustrate an example, bad choice - going to change the keys to make it reflect a more appropriate sample. Nice catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two window functions to designate series and aggregate functions to get the longest streak:

```
select distinct on (player_id)
    player_id, 
    max(match_id) as match_id, 
    count(*) as streak
from (
    select 
        player_id, match_id, score, 
        sum(grp) over w as grp
    from (
        select 
            player_id, match_id, score, 
            (score < 0 and lag(score, 1, 1) over w > 0)::int as grp
        from my_view
        window w as (partition by player_id order by match_id)
        ) s
    window w as (partition by player_id order by match_id)
    ) s
where score > 0
group by player_id, grp
order by player_id desc, streak desc

 player_id | match_id | streak 
-----------+----------+--------
        82 |     5363 |      5
        51 |     5037 |      3
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. Took me a while to find the time to implement it, and then figure out what it does, how it works, and how I can tweak it to my needs (also discovered a mistake in my view, so it was a painful but helpful exercise). I left out the "distinct" clause and max, because I'm interested in *all* streaks, not just every player's best streak. But I guess that wasn't clear in my post, so it's on my, and after all it just all helped me to further my understanding of Postgres. Now I can do lots of funny things with this. Thanks!